# How can Resource Owner grant Client and do not give its information?

Tags: oauth-2.0

When I read [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) , there is a image shows the process:

[image]

I don't understand the steps' function that can avoid give Resource Owner's information to Client:
**Client ask Resource Owner for Authorization( step A ), and Resource Owner give the Grant for Client( step B ).**

How can the step A and step B avoid to give the Resource Owner's information to Client?

Answer (score 1):

The resource owner password grant counts with the client getting access to the resource owner's credentials. The goal of this grant is to be there if you cannot use other flows (e.g. when a backend needs a token for itself). As the [OAuth 2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-9) says:

> The credentials should only be used when there is a high
> degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the
> client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged
> application), and when other authorization grant types are not
> available (such as an authorization code).

If you don't want the client to get the credentials, use some other flow such as Implicit or Authorization code grant.